# wpf ListBox looks like datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, listbox

I have a listbox control in my app.
I want to change his style to being look like to Datagrid (borders, columns, row...).
I don't want to using stantard datagrid - because its control cannot binding itemtemplte.
I trying to do it:

```
 <ListBox 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    Name="listBox1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                        <TextBlock   Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="5"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                        <TextBlock   Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

But it not looking good - as following:

[image]

it what i want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to make each item a uniform size in the list box?

Comment: *I don't want to using stantard datagrid - because its control cannot binding itemtemplte*... care to elaborate on this sentence? I think that you *could* be mistaken and *could* use a `DataGrid` after all.

Comment: i can to change the lisbox, what i need? 3 things - itemsource for binding the my observable list, and itemtemplate for binding custom elements, and the last thing - style like excel or datagrid - i mean that every cell will be bordered and uniform size to maxmum width.

Comment: selector? do you mean to select current row? so yes - its inside a popup control - i implement custom autocomplete and popup a listboxitems for the user - that need to select a row...

Comment: instead of write complex control - it's mot possible to using stackpanel or someting like it into itemtemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Grid.IsSharedSizeScope**

result

[image: SharedSizeScope example]

i believe you want the columns to be re-sized based on your string length, so Grid.IsSharedSizeScope is your choice here

example xaml

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="name" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="Black">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                     Margin="5" />
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderBrush="Black">
                        <TextBlock   Text="{Binding Id}"
                                     Margin="5" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

if you move SharedSizeGroup to id like below

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="id" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

result

[image: SharedSizeScope example 2]

**Using ListView with GridView**

You have an option to use list view with grid view which will have same appearance as grid with flexibility of list

eg

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SourceItems}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Column1"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column1}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Column2"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column2}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

GridViewColumn offers you to modify CellTemplate, HeaderTemplate, HeaderContainerStyle, HeaderStringFormat etc.

Comment: thanks, but i don't want to use listview+gridview, it's because i cannot binding custom itemtemplate into gridview..

Comment: you can use CellTemplate to specify your custom template.

Comment: CellTemplate is specify custom template for every column - i meant that i want to bind a itemtemplate to Columns, it not possible in gridView, for gridview, i need to write: GridView->GridView.Columns->...

Comment: ok could you post a picture of your expected output, may I try to create the same.

Comment: i edited my question and attached an image for what i expect to get.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can achieve this using a grid control (It supports binding and everything else)

To fix your problem, you will have to give fixed widths to both your borders inside your stackpanel then your listbox items will look like a grid control.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Border Width="150" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                        <TextBlock   Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="5"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border Width="50" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                        <TextBlock   Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
```

Please let us know what problem you are having with GridControl and maybe we can fix that as well

Edit. If you were using a DataGrid your template would look like

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text={Binding Id}/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text={Binding Name}/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Please note that I have set HeaderVisibility to false so that it doesnt look like a datagrid but instead looks like a list

Comment: thanks, i don't want to set fixed width, because soemtimes have a long sentence or short sentence - i want to extend the listboxitem to max width of the longest item. grid control? do you mean to datagrid? or to Grid? the grid can getting itemsource? and style itemtemplate?

Comment: sorry GridControl, you can define itemssource and then templates for your data items

Comment: wpf doesn't have a GridControl - do you mean to devexpress control?

Comment: Oops sorry yeah I have been working with Devexpress GridControl so I got confused. You can use DataGrid and still use your DataTemplates though?

Comment: Datagrid is problemtic:\ because i cannot to binding columns - i need to write inside the columns...